# Find all words which have no specific character before

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find all words that have no specific character before?

For example, if I want to match all `apple`, which have no any character `b` before it, how should I do?

> dolphin elephant **apple** star    <-- Matched
>   dog cat **apple** banana            <-- Matched
>   map banana *apple* dog           <-- Unmatched (Since there's a `b` before the `apple`)
>   map **apple** banana *apple* cat <-- The first `apple` matched, but the second one unmatched.
>   map **apple** banana *apple* banana *apple* <-- Only the first `apple` matched, others are unmatched.
>   map **apple** dog **apple** banana *apple* banana *apple* <-- The first `apple` and the second `apple` matched, others are unmatched.

Here's my try:

```
/(?<!.*b.*)apple/g
```

And of course, the regex above is invalid, since the quantifier (asterisk in this case) inside the lookbehind makes it non-fixed width. So how should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `/^[^b]*apple/`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that the word `apple` can match multiple times.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Javascript. But I hope I can only use regex to find that word.

Comment: Then your first problem is that JavaScript doesn't support look-behind, not that it's variable-width.

Comment: `/[^b]*apple/y` could work but IE doesn't support `y`.

Comment: Why is it you only want to use regex? Just split by spaces and iterate while checking your condition.

Comment: But not only in Javascript but also in PHP, the same regex still not work. The quantifier seems not allowed in lookbehind pattern.

Comment: An idea to split once and rejoin at specific char/str. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxvxkc9z/).

Comment: @bluecat Please check my answer. I had to re-post due to some revenge downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been mentioned already that there is no lookbehind available in JS regex. To me it reads like you want to match and eventually replace the matched words before the specific character.

I would split the string at the first occurence and [capture the split sequence](https://regex101.com/r/O05wmj/1). Then match/replace only in the first part and rejoin the parts afterwards. `[^]*` matches just any characters.

```js
// Test strings
var strs = ['dolphin elephant apple star','dog cat apple banana','map banana apple dog',
'map apple banana apple cat','map apple banana apple banana apple',
'map apple dog apple banana apple banana apple'];

// Split string at separator - Replace in first part - Rejoin
for (var str of strs) {
  var parts = str.split(/(b[^]*)/);
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\b(apple)\b/g, '<b>$1</b>');
  var new_str = parts.join('');
  
  // Check result
  console.log(new_str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, search for the first occurence of the character. Then take the substring from 0 to that index and match the pattern against the substring. If the character is not found, then just search the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Regex flavors differ. What you cannot do with a pure regex can usuaully be compensated with the code.

.NET, Python PyPi regex engines support infinite width lookbehind patterns, your approach will work there (see [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!b.*%29apple&i=dolphin+elephant+apple+star%0d%0adog+cat+apple+banana%0d%0a%0d%0amap+banana+apple+dog%0d%0a%0d%0amap+apple+banana+apple+cat%0d%0amap+apple+banana+apple+banana+apple%0d%0a%0d%0amap+apple+dog+apple+banana+apple+banana+apple)).

In Java, `(?<!b.{0,1000})apple` will work as Java regex engine supports a *constrained-width* lookbehind pattern (tested at [OCPSoftware regex tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/)).

In PHP, you may use [known `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` PCRE verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to skip what you do not need, use [`b.*?apple(*SKIP)(*F)|apple`](https://regex101.com/r/jFIFci/1)).

In JavaScript and Python `re`, use an optional *capturing* group and check if it was matched. If it matched, the match should be discarded, else, grab it.

Here is a JS implementation (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fACvCf/1/)):

```js
var ss = ['dolphin elephant apple star','dog cat apple banana','map banana apple dog','map apple banana apple cat','map apple banana apple banana apple','map apple dog apple banana apple banana apple'];
var rx = /(b.*?)?apple/g;
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log("Testing '"+s+"'.....");
  var m;
  while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
     if (!m[1]) console.log(m[0]," at ", m.index);
  }
  console.log("===================");
}
```